# How to keep menu active status while scrolling between section

Tags: javascript, scroll, gsap, scrollmagic, superscrollorama

The active menu status not working while scrolling between `<section>`. Is there any option in scrollMagic to set active status all the time while scrolling based on which `<section>` is `.setPin()` ?

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
  globalSceneOptions: {
    duration: $('section').height(),
    triggerHook: .025,
    reverse: true
  }
});
$("section").each(function() {
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: this,
        duration: '50%',
        triggerHook: 0.025,
        reverse: true
    })
    .setPin(this)
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/mobrndstr/pen/pymGoQ

nav menu `.active` status removes in between two section while scrolling.

---

when `<section class="feature" id="intro">` Section `.setPin()`

[image]

---

In between `<section class="feature" id="intro">` to `<section class="feature" id="feature">` active status gone

[image]

---

And `.active` statu`<section class="feature" id="feature">` has set as `setPin()`

[image]

Comment: @thepio please give me 1min let me update to the question

Comment: Yep, I will follow this post.

Comment: Yes I understand your problem. Let me take a look :)

Comment: @thepio I do appreciate your help

Comment: I'm sorry but I had to leave to do other things yesterday and came back this morning and tried it one more time. I think there needs to be a lot of changes (if I'm not missing something obvious) to the code to be able to get it to work the way you want it to. I might take a look at a solution later on today if someone has not got you an answer already.